# RETURN inside a transaction with TRY-CATCH block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following code, and I am wondering, as a generic example, if the transaction is left open if it exits with `RETURN`.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblProducts WHERE intProductID = @intProductID)
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'Product does not exists' AS strMessage
                RETURN
            END

        UPDATE dbo.tblProducts SET
            curPrice = 10
        WHERE
            intProductID = @intProductID

        SELECT 'Success' AS strMessage

    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS strMessage
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes", the transaction is left open.  Transactions are not conditioned on the context of the stored procedure; they are the state within the database.  However, the documentation is pretty clear on this point, and you are talking about subtleties of the database, so I suggest you read the SQL Server documentation.

Comment: I would just pull the exists and evaluate @@rowcount  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: Or use an `OUTPUT` clause on the `UPDATE` if you want to know what was changed without doing an `EXISTS` test.  (A variation on Blam's comment.)  My preference is to have every exit path explicitly commit or rollback.  It shows that I actually made a decision.

Comment: My suggestion was going to be to move the `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` statements so that they encapsulate the minimum commands necessary. Doing this highlights that in this example the transaction is redundant; the `UPDATE` is the only statement over which it can have any effect  - and the `UPDATE` is by definition atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works with nested transactions:

```
BEGIN TRY
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      SAVE TRANSACTION MyTransactionName
   ELSE
       BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTransactionName

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblProducts WHERE intProductID = @intProductID)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'Product does not exists' AS strMessage
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTransactionName
            RETURN
        END

    UPDATE dbo.tblProducts SET
        curPrice = 10
    WHERE
        intProductID = @intProductID

    SELECT 'Success' AS strMessage

    COMMIT TRANSACTION MyTransactionName
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS strMessage
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTransactionName
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be like Below

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblProducts 
                          WHERE intProductID = @intProductID)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'Product does not exists' AS strMessage
            Rollback TRan
            RETURN
        END

        UPDATE dbo.tblProducts SET
        curPrice = 10
        WHERE
        intProductID = @intProductID

        SELECT 'Success' AS strMessage
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS strMessage
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that using TRY, CATCH means you've got to `RAISERROR` for it to be treated as an error. This approach is fine if the OP is just running this once in the terminal but if it's got to go into production best that people know to `RAISERROR` in the CATCH to avoid it just failing silently.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this by running the code above then checking `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` and then by attempting a `ROLLBACK`. After the return, `@@TRANCOUNT` was 1 and I was able to `rollback` the transaction successfully indicating that the `transaction` is left open.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Stored Procedure template that I posted in the following DBA.StackExchange answer as it address the use of TRY / CATCH with Transactions, and it handles nested calls, even if the Transaction is opened in the app layer:

[Are we required to handle Transaction in C# Code as well as in Store procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93258/are-we-required-to-handle-transaction-in-c-code-as-well-as-in-store-procedure/93265#93265)